# How to use foreign words in English writing

Tags: italics, foreign-phrases

*Nonna* is a word that means grandmother in Italian. If I italicize in the beginning like this: "Nine years ago, *nonna* (Italian grandmother), ..." then I don't have to continue italicizing the word however I'm confused about how to address this character in the future.

Since nonna means grandmother, do I use the word the same way I would use grandmother? For example, would i say "my nonna" as opposed to "nonna" even though I call her nonna? In other words, I say "nonna" to address my grandmother, as if 'nonna' is her name.

Comment: "Nine years ago my grandmother Nonna ..."  Most English speakers will recognize the word as a foreign term for "grandmother", and I see no need to explain it further if this is not some sort of formal writing.

Comment: Thanks! So if I said "Nine years ago my grandmother Nonna..." i wouldn't have to italicize it right? and it is for an essay, so I'm not sure if you think that is formal writing or not

Comment: I think it would work fine when telling personal history, even as an essay.  And do note that it should be capitalized if it was the word you used to address her.  Capitalization might not be appropriate if you always said "my nonna".

Comment: Uh, "Nine years ago my grandmother Nonna" means that your grandmother's *first name* was "Nonna". That is absolutely not what you are trying to say. And no, do not use the parenthetical explanation, either. That immediately breaks the flow and ruins the tone. It is at odds with the nature and style of the personal story you're telling here. Look for a way to explain it that doesn't sound like technical documentation. For example, "Nine years ago, my grandmother, whom I always simply called *nonna*...". Or something to that extent.

Comment: And then from there on, treat it like you would in Italian. No article, no possessive pronoun. "I went to nonna and asked her for advice." "That Christmas, nonna was really happy." Not my nonna, not the nonna, not a nonna. Just nonna. No italics, either.

Comment: "Nine years ago, Nonna (_nonna_ is Italian for grandmother)  ...". We'd use 'Grandma' more intimately, as a title, but 'my grandmother' more clinically, in a piece of scientific or other reference writing, as a term of general reference. Compare say 'Rex' and 'my dog'. It's unusual to use close relatives' given names (unless there are obviously forcing circumstances, as when answering "What's your mother's mother called?"), eg 'Gertrude', though 'Grandma Gertie' or 'Grandma Wilson' are commonly used, especially to disambiguate.

Answer (score 1):

English common nouns usually need a determiner like *the, my, this*. And in this case, if you don't capitalize *nonna*, you have made it a common noun and it needs *my* before it (even as a foreign word). English proper nouns don't need one.

So the first time you introduce her in the story, you should say

> my nonna (Italian grandmother).

After that, you can call her Nonna, capitalized and without *my*.

Answer (score 0):

> If I italicize in the beginning like this: "Nine years ago, nonna (Italian grandmother), ..." then I don't have to continue italicizing the word

The approach here is not universal. Different style guides might advise different approaches.

> Since nonna means grandmother, do I use the word the same way I would use grandmother? For example, would i say "my nonna" as opposed to "nonna" even though I call her nonna?

It's a judgement call -- both are options. Saying things like "my nonna" would give the writing a very intimate, personal tone. Using "my grandmother" would match a personal tone or a more detached tone.

Comment: Thank you! So would it be correct if I stated that nonna meant grandmother like I did earlier, but then write nonna as if it were her name? So even though I initially said 'nonna' lowercase to show that it means grandmother, would it be okay to continue later saying things like 'I was hungry so Nonna made me something to eat."? Or would I leave it as "I was hungry so nonna made me something to eat."

Comment: If you call her "nonna" then capitalize: "I asked Nonna about her childhood."

Comment: i can do that even though I initially introduced her by saying "Nine years ago, nonna (Italian grandmother), ..." ?

Comment: Because I made 'nonna' lowercase in that sentence. so is it ok for me to switch to capital? So i can say 'Nine years ago, nonna (Italian grandmother)..." and then right after say "I asked Nonna about her childhood"?

Comment: @user130306: if you're not capitalizing *nonna*, you should say *my nonna*, because it's not a proper noun. But after that, you can switch to calling her *Nonna* (without the *my*).

Answer (score 0):

Nonna means grandmother...in english, most people refer to their grandmother as “my grandmother” when speaking to unrelated people.  So you would say “my nonna”.  But, there are those people who loom so large in life that everyone uses those terms.  Also, if the shorty is being told from your perspective rather than told by you, then you can leave off “my”

Comment: In English, people sometimes just say *Grandma* (without a *my*), even when talking to unrelated people. So you could just use *Nonna*.